# In what ways can you trust a third party server with your data?

Tags: server, trust

What can you do that will make it easier for you to trust a third-party server? For example, using Intel sgx enclaves.

Comment: Encrypt the data using a key that only you know, and only send the encrypted data to the server.

Comment: If it's their hardware, it's their data. You would be better off vetting the owner than trying to lock down the hardware. But it all depends on your threat model, like anything in infosec.

Comment: Trusting for doing what exactly? Just storing the data or analyzing the data or augmenting the data or ... ? In some case crypto might solve the problem, in other SGX might reduce the problem but in some cases none of these will help. And then there is the legal aspect, i.e. what risks does the third party have if it does not deal properly with your data and would profits from misuse be worth this risk? In summary: the question is in the current form too broad to be answerable.

Comment: Encrypt it before you store it on third-party servers.  Otherwise, any admin on that server can probably access the data.  Legal contracts, NDA's, etc. be damned.  Companies agree to legal contracts.  A pissed-off sysadmin wont care.  He can get the data and quit the company before anyone finds out.  You might still be able to sue them for the breach, but you've still lost the data and possibly the trust of your customers.

Answer (score 1):

This depends completely on your situation.

As a private person, there is little you can do. You can read-up on the provider. Is this a trustworthy party? Or is it a party that easily sells its data? Read the fine print of the EULA. If the provider has a history of data leaks, they should be in the news. Is the provider is in a jurisdiction that forces the handover of all data and has a gagging-order history? You might want to avoid that, unless you trust that government.

ISO norms may give you some more reason to trust a provider.

As a company, you may look at your contracts. A smaller provider will generally be more willing to accommodate you. As a company, we normally have a right to audit (which we actually do too), which gives us more trust. There is also the possibility of independent audits.